# OperatingSystemMXBean getProcessCpuTime() in JDK7+

Tags: java

I see code for jdk6 that has the following OperatingSystemMXBean method :

```
OperatingSystemMXBean osbean = 
    (OperatingSystemMXBean)      ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();

long prevProcessCpuTime = osbean.getProcessCpuTime();
```

In the JDK7 docs there appears not to be any mention of them.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html

[image]

Are there any equivalents to the jdk6 method elsewhere in the jdk7+ ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getProcessCpuTime--

Comment: @JigarJoshi   Ah so jdk8 brought back that method - and added some new ones. thx!  Feel free to make this an answer.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getProcessCpuTime%28%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at wrong place in API doc, It is there in 7

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getProcessCpuTime%28%29

Comment: ah ok there are two versions of that interface: one in `java.lang.management` and the other in `com.sun.management`

Comment: There is more to it .. I added an answer with the required cast.

Answer (score 1):

It is required to cast the result:

```
val obs = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
           .getOperatingSystemMXBean.asInstanceOf
          [com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBeanOperatingSystemMXBean]
```

Comment: Is this actually java? Seems more like Scala.

Comment: y but this is an api call- does not matter if invoked scala, groovy, clojure, jruby..